# Nvidia gpu not selected on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04

Installed using software update ->additional drivers ->using nvidia driver metapackage from driver-460 (prop,tested).

On nvidia x server settings i see  prime profiles -> nvidia performance mode checked.

On settings-> about i see my integrated gpu not my nvidia graphics card.

If i run sudo nvidia-settings the output is
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

(nvidia-settings:2417): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:13:57.998: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 16:13:58.001: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 16:13:58.001: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 16:13:58.027: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 16:13:58.027: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 16:13:58.027: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes

HELP PLEASE !

EDIT: mokutil --sb-state says that secured boot is enabled but on the BIOS is Disabled(???) .

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by disabling secure boot from the terminal following this guide :
METHOD 2
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS